# Do two different constant functions exist with a single element domain?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I have 2 constant functions $f: M \rightarrow M$ and $g: M \rightarrow M$. If M only contains one element, why does $g \circ  f \neq f \circ g$, if $g$ and $f$ are not identical? I could prove that generally, but if M only contains one Element, arent the two functions automatically identical??

Edit: Added information

Comment: There is only one function from $M$ to $M$

Comment: @user251257 ... Hmm okay. That's kinda weird because in the exercise I was asked, why the inequality also holds, even if M only has one element (given the functions are different) ...

Comment: It is a question, isn't it. It may be true or not ...

Comment: @user251257 Ah sorry for the bad translation then: It literally asks me to prove that it is true.. I assume, if what you said is right then either I did not understand the question or (more likely) there is a typo in the exercise.

Comment: Hm... are these total or partial functions?

Comment: Oh, I seem to have deleted that from the original questions: It is given that they are constant functions.

Comment: If $M$ is a singleton there is exactly one function $M \to M$, so $f=g$.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have pointed out it is impossible for $ f \neq g $ if $M$ is singleton.  The only way $ g \circ f \neq f \circ g$ could be true is via the Principle of explosion that states that everything is true if a falsehood is true.